# Edit html with css but now classes

Tags: html, css

I'm getting ready for a test and one of the main topics will be changing an HTML style using CSS but we can't use HTML classes or edit the HTML.

In order to change the background I used Article and it selected everything inside and the background was changed, I managed to change the color of Hidden and Green by selecting it using only-child, but then I tried with the other ones and couldn't manage to do it.

It should look like this: https://clickio.gyazo.com/97fa4884c612a1653b4b3245d102eb52

```css
article {
  background-color: gray;
}

p:only-child {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p>Green</p>
  <p>Blue</p>
  <div>
    <p>Red centered</p>
  </div>
  <p>Yellow</p>
  <p>Green</p>
  <div class="hidden">
    <p>Hidden</p>
  </div>
  <p>Green</p>
  <p>Green</p>
  <p>Purple</p>
  <p>Pink</p>
  <hr>
</article>
```

Comment: You can use the `id` as well, or force a style on the tag, in HTML (this is a bad practice though, you shouldn't really do it). So, I think you could use `id`.

Comment: try to use the `:nth-child` selector instead of `:only-child`

Comment: @manjirosano I can't edit the HTML at all :c

Comment: @tacoshy I replace nth-child but it does not work, how should I proceed, I mean to use it?

Comment: @AngelArias You said in the post that you couldn't use classes. If you can't, why did you use it there?

Comment: @manjirosano its a task given by his school, he gets a html markup and have to chaneg the stylign withotu touching the HTML. The class "hidden" was proberly already set at that time.

Comment: @tacoshy oh, that explains the usage of the class hidden! xd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize `nth-child()` for your task:

```css
article {
  background-color: gray;
}

article > :nth-child(1),
article > :nth-child(5),
article > :nth-child(7),
article > :nth-child(8) {
  color: green;
}

article > :nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}

article > :nth-child(4) {
  color: yellow;
}

article > :nth-child(9) {
  color: purple;
}

article > :nth-child(10) {
  color: pink;
}

article > :nth-child(3) {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p>Green</p>
  <p>Blue</p>
  <div>
    <p>Red centered</p>
  </div>
  <p>Yellow</p>
  <p>Green</p>
  <div class="hidden">
    <p>Hidden</p>
  </div>
  <p>Green</p>
  <p>Green</p>
  <p>Purple</p>
  <p>Pink</p>
  <hr>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty close to the expectations..

It's a matter of crafting css selectors to address the correct elements to style. The demo I'm showing here uses a different css rule for each element. There are surely several ways to style the document as expected and this isn't surely the most compact one. By the way I used mostly the following pseudo-slectors:

- `:nth-child()`
- `:nth-of-type()`

```css
article {
  background-color: gray;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

article > p:first-child{
  color: green;
}

article > p:nth-child(2){
  color: blue;  
}

article > div:nth-of-type(1){
  text-align: center;  
  color: red;
  background: white;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 3rem;
}

article > p:nth-child(4){
  color: yellow;
}

article > p:nth-child(5) {
  color: green;
}

article > div.hidden {
  display: none;
}

article > p:nth-child(7) {
  color: green;
}

article > p:nth-child(8) {
  color: green;
}

article > p:nth-child(9) {
  color: purple;
}

article > p:nth-child(10) {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p>Green</p>
  <p>Blue</p>
  <div>
    <p>Red centered</p>
  </div>
  <p>Yellow</p>
  <p>Green</p>
  <div class="hidden">
    <p>Hidden</p>
  </div>
  <p>Green</p>
  <p>Green</p>
  <p>Purple</p>
  <p>Pink</p>
  <hr>
</article>
```